# Where did I go wrong with this R code involving the train function?

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R and I do not know why I get the following:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The code is the following:

```
banknote=read.csv('banknote.csv', header = F)
head(banknote)
library(naivebayes)
library(caret)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)
library(MASS)
attach(banknote)
class=as.factor(banknote[,5])
class
data=banknote[,1:4]
data
nb=train(class~., method='naive_bayes',data=banknote[,1:4], trControl=trainControl(method="LOOCV"),preProcess=c("center","scale"))


> nb=train(class~., method='naive_bayes',data=banknote[,1:4], trControl=trainControl(method="LOOCV"),preProcess=c("center","scale"))
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

And the banknote file looks like this:

```
3.6216,8.6661,-2.8073,-0.44699,0
4.5459,8.1674,-2.4586,-1.4621,0
3.866,-2.6383,1.9242,0.10645,0
3.4566,9.5228,-4.0112,-3.5944,0
0.32924,-4.4552,4.5718,-0.9888,0
4.3684,9.6718,-3.9606,-3.1625,0
3.5912,3.0129,0.72888,0.56421,0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change `data=banknote[,1:4]` to `data=banknote` in your `nb` model! :-) Or provide a `dput` of your data so we can have a better look!

Comment: Can you provide some data? See how to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix the issue?

```
data14 = banknote[,1:4]
data14
nb = train(class~., method='naive_bayes', data=data14, trControl=trainControl(method="LOOCV"), preProcess=c("center","scale"))
```